# The pagination doesn't work properly, doesn't return on previous page

Tags: php, html

Make my pet project (war criminals database-Ukranian War). And have problem with paggination- the Previus dont work( the error ).(Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]). Another parts working.

Here my controller function

```
public function Latest_Items()
    {include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\WarCriminalsDatabase\database_connection.php';
       
         $paginations=$this->i_model->paginations;
        // $page_counter=$this->i_model->page_counter;
        $start=$this->i_model->start;
        $perPage=$this->i_model->perPage;
        $pagLink=$this->i_model->pagLink;

       
          if (!isset($_GET['items'])) {
                $paginations-$this->i_model->pugination($conn);
              $pokidky = $this->i_model->get_all_pokidky_pagination($conn);
              $category = $this->c_model->get_all_category($conn);
              include 'Views\MainPageView.php';
          }
        
    }
```

Here The functions in Model class.

```
function pugination($conn)
    {
        $this->start = 1;
        $this->perPage = 4;
        $this->page_counter = 1;
        
        if (isset($_GET['start'])) {
            $this->start = $_GET['start'];
            //$this->offset = $this->start* $this->perPage = 8;
            //  $this->page_counter =  $_GET['start'];
             $this->start = $this->start * $this->perPage;
            // $this->next = $this->page_counter + 1;
            // $this->previous = $this->page_counter - 1;
        }
        else {
            $this->start = 1;
        }

        $count_query = "SELECT * FROM pokidky ORDER by id ASC";
        $query = $conn->prepare($count_query);
        $query->execute();
        $count = $query->rowCount();
        // calculate the pagination number by dividing total number of rows with per page.
        $this->paginations = ceil($count / $this->perPage);
        return  $this->paginations;
    }

    function get_all_pokidky_pagination($conn)
    {
       $this->pugination($conn);

       $this->start = 1;
       $this->perPage = 4;
       $this->page_counter = 1;
       
       if (isset($_GET['start'])) {
           $this->start = $_GET['start'];
           //$this->offset = $this->start* $this->perPage = 8;
           //  $this->page_counter =  $_GET['start'];
            $this->start = ($this->start * $this->perPage) ;
           // $this->next = $this->page_counter + 1;
           // $this->previous = $this->page_counter - 1;
       }
       else {
           $this->start = 1;
       }


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM pokidky ORDER by id ASC LIMIT $this->start, $this->perPage";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $pokidky = $stmt->fetchAll();
        } else {
            $pokidky = 0;
        }
        
        return $pokidky;
    }
```

The html part in View page.

```
<pre>
   <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="page-item" <?php if ($start <= 1) {
             echo 'disabled';
             } ?>><a class="page-link" href="<?php if ($start >= 1) 
             { echo '#';  } else { echo "?start=" . ($start - 1);
               } ?>">Previous</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?start=0">First</a></li>
                <li class="page-item" <?php if ($start >= 1) {
                echo 'disabled';
                } ?>><a class="page-link" href="<?php if ($start >= 1) {
                    echo '#';
                             } else {
                             echo "?start=" . ($start + 1);
                             } ?>">Next</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?pagination=<?php echo $paginations; ?>">Last</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
</pre
```

will be glad if you help me. Admins  please dont bann me. Maybe my questions is stupid, but I think that no stupid questions, couse this site for asking help, simple or hard all questions are matter. Also I will be glad if you explain me all in very simle words, my english not very good, I very sorry for it.